# printing unique values with IEnumerable<string>

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have lots of places in my code where values are IEnumerable
and they repeat many times...sometimes all the times

instead of printing the same value many times how can i set to print only the unique values
?

thats just an example of how i print IEnumerable

```
 .Select(g => new DTO
                    {
                        VALU = g.Select(z => z.BARBAR),
                    });

                return query;


   public class DTO
    {  
   public virtual IEnumerable<string> BARBAR { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you post a more complete code sample? You've included half a LINQ query, and half a class definition. It's not clear what `g` is and you haven't showed how you are printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Distinct:

```
VALU = g.Select(z => z.BARBAR).Distinct()
```

Comment: well i tried it but somehow it not working all the time...is that working for you all the time?

Comment: @Alexxx that means that you should override Equals to return true when the object properties are the same (according to your's logic)